# Is the command in a process substitution invoked in a subshell?

Tags: bash, process-substitution, subshell

From the bash manual

> **Process substitution** is supported on systems that support **named pipes**
>   (fifos) or the `/dev/fd` method of naming open files.    It takes the form 
>   of
>
> ```
> <(list)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> >(list)
> ```
>
> The process
>   list is run with its input or output connected to a fifo or some file
>   in `/dev/fd`. The name of this file is passed as an argument to the
>   current command as the result of the expansion.

Is the command `list` in a process substitution `<(list)` or `>(list)` invoked in a subshell, similarly to  a command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and
 asynchronous commands? Similar as the bash manual says

> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and
>   asynchronous commands are **invoked in a subshell environment** that
>   is a duplicate of the shell environment,  except that traps caught by
>   the shell are reset to the values that the shell inherited from its
>   parent at invocation.

1. The answer might be yes, because

   - process substitution looks similar to command substitution,
   - [some source](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) says that

     > the command inside it is run in the background.

   and the above second quote from the bash manual says that both command
   substitution and backgrounded commands are invoked in subshells.
2. The answer might be no, because

   - In the bash manual, I didn't see that a process substitution is    mentioned in the above second quote from the bash manual,
   - and [some source](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) says that process substitution

     > is especially important for bypassing subshells caused by pipelines

     although I am not sure if "bypassing subshells" means not being    invoked in a subshell.

Answer (score 3):

Running the current shell under `strace(1)` and then executing e.g.  `<(command)` gives:

```
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fa6713d59d0) = 13305
```

From a purely definitional standpoint, since [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) is defined as

> create a child process

and a [subshell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) as

> Running a shell script launches a new process, a subshell.

one could say that yes - running process substitution is invoked as a subshell.

Comment: I ran the following in a terminal: `a=$$; b=$(cat <(echo $$)); if [ $a -eq $b ]; then echo "NOT in a subshell"; else echo "in a subshell"; fi`. The output was: `NOT in a subshell`

Comment: @Harry I think that is happening there is that all the `$$` get evaluated by the top-level shell.

Comment: But compare the output of `pstree -p $$`, `echo $(pstree -p $$)`, `(pstree -p $$)`, and `(echo $(pstree -p $$))` - on my machine, only the process substitution inside the subshell actually spawns another subshell.