# non-deterministic output from independent processes run concurrently by process substitution

Tags: bash, tee, process-substitution

On `bash` *v4.1.2(2)*, the following simple statement, chosen merely as a minimal example demonstrating the problem, gives seemingly random output:

```
$ for n in {0..1000}; do echo "$n"; done | 
  tee >(head -n2) >(sort -grk1,1 | head -n3) >/dev/null
```

whereas the following gives consistent output:

```
$ seq 0 10000 | tee >(head -n2) >(sort -grk1,1 | head -n3) >/dev/null
```

Specifically, for the first statement, the `sort` command chooses apparently random consecutive triplets (e.g., 226,225,224; 52,51,50; 174,173,172; etc.). To get a sense of the heterogeneity of the output, one can run the problematic command many times, and then list the number of distinct possibilities:

```
$ seq -w 0 2000 | while read x; do for n in {0..1000}; do echo "$n"; done | 
  tee >(head -n2) >(sort -grk1,1 | head -n3) >/dev/null | cat > "file_${x}"; done
```

Counting the occurrences of the various outputs:

```
$ for f in file_*; do sort -g "$f" | tail -n3 | paste -sd, ; done  | 
  sort | uniq -c | sort -gk1,1 -k2,2
   1 7,8,9
   1 17,18,19
   1 40,41,42
   1 43,44,45
   1 47,48,49
   1 50,51,52
   1 54,55,56
   1 58,59,60
   1 59,60,61
   1 66,67,68
   1 71,72,73
   1 78,79,80
   1 103,104,105
   1 104,105,106
   1 106,107,108
   1 110,111,112
   1 111,112,113
   1 121,122,123
   1 125,126,127
   1 129,130,131
   1 134,135,136
   1 136,137,138
   1 142,143,144
   1 143,144,145
   1 148,149,150
   1 150,151,152
   1 156,157,158
   1 157,158,159
   1 165,166,167
   1 171,172,173
   1 173,174,175
   1 174,175,176
   1 177,178,179
   1 179,180,181
   1 181,182,183
   1 183,184,185
   1 185,186,187
   1 186,187,188
   1 191,192,193
   1 194,195,196
   1 198,199,200
   1 200,201,202
   1 206,207,208
   1 208,209,210
   1 209,210,211
   1 210,211,212
   1 216,217,218
   1 217,218,219
   1 233,234,235
   1 236,237,238
   1 237,238,239
   1 238,239,240
   1 242,243,244
   1 245,246,247
   1 246,247,248
   1 254,255,256
   1 256,257,258
   1 267,268,269
   1 270,271,272
   1 273,274,275
   1 277,278,279
   1 279,280,281
   1 287,288,289
   1 288,289,290
   1 305,306,307
   1 306,307,308
   1 307,308,309
   1 326,327,328
   1 337,338,339
   1 339,340,341
   1 340,341,342
   1 351,352,353
   1 357,358,359
   1 359,360,361
   1 365,366,367
   1 368,369,370
   1 370,371,372
   1 376,377,378
   1 377,378,379
   1 383,384,385
   1 386,387,388
   1 388,389,390
   1 401,402,403
   1 408,409,410
   1 409,410,411
   1 415,416,417
   1 419,420,421
   1 424,425,426
   1 426,427,428
   1 432,433,434
   1 454,455,456
   1 462,463,464
   1 466,467,468
   1 475,476,477
   1 482,483,484
   1 487,488,489
   1 504,505,506
   1 508,509,510
   1 511,512,513
   1 532,533,534
   1 538,539,540
   1 544,545,546
   1 548,549,550
   1 558,559,560
   1 603,604,605
   1 604,605,606
   1 608,609,610
   1 659,660,661
   1 660,661,662
   1 663,664,665
   1 668,669,670
   1 692,693,694
   1 699,700,701
   1 717,718,719
   1 738,739,740
   1 740,741,742
   1 750,751,752
   1 771,772,773
   1 784,785,786
   1 796,797,798
   1 799,800,801
   1 806,807,808
   1 814,815,816
   1 832,833,834
   1 848,849,850
   1 858,859,860
   1 869,870,871
   1 922,923,924
   1 952,953,954
   1 961,962,963
   1 985,986,987
   2 64,65,66
   2 127,128,129
   2 141,142,143
   2 169,170,171
   2 170,171,172
   2 172,173,174
   2 187,188,189
   2 221,222,223
   2 234,235,236
   2 252,253,254
   2 292,293,294
   2 350,351,352
   2 364,365,366
   2 375,376,377
   2 622,623,624
   2 666,667,668
   3 70,71,72
   3 102,103,104
   3 137,138,139
   3 155,156,157
1826 998,999,1000
```

shows that the result is correct ~91% of the time. Omitting the `>(head -n2)` process substitution from the `tee` statement results in the output being correct 100% of the time. I don't see why a race condition would be relevant in explaining the problem, since that should only affect the relative ordering of the output of each of the process substitutions in the`tee` statement (i.e., `>(head -n2)` may complete first or `>(sort -grk1,1 | head -n3)` may do so, but this should only affect the output order, not the result itself; it would even be understandable if the output of the two commands were randomly interleaved). Since `tee` should distribute identical copies of the `stdout` of the loop to the `stdin` of each `>()` and since both process substitutions are run in separate sub-shells (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331199/14960), neither one should affect the other, yet they clearly interact. How can the interaction be explained? Also, how can the output of a `for`/`while` loop in `bash` be distributed to multiple, independent processes by `tee`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`head -n2` will quit after reading two lines. Then `tee` will die (of a SIGPIPE) the next time it writes to the pipe to `head`, then `sort` will see eof as `tee` at the other end of its own pipe is also gone and sort on the lines it has received so far.

The reason why you're seeing it with the loop and not with seq is that the loop does several `write()`s on the pipe to `tee`, and depending on timing, that will likely cause `tee` to do several short reads. While `seq` will write the whole output in one go so `tee` will just do one `read()`. If you do a `seq 1000000`, you'll probably see *random* behaviour as well.

To work around the problem, you'd need a version of `head` that keeps reading after it has output the first 2 lines. For instance, you could use 
`sed '3,$d'` instead of `head -n2` or `sed 2q`.

Or use:

```
... | (
 trap '' PIPE
 exec tee >(trap - PIPE; exec head -n2) >(trap - PIPE; sort -rn | head -n2)
) > /dev/null
```

for `tee` (only) to ignore the SIGPIPE, but with some `tee` implementations, you'd see some error messages because of the failing `write()` to the pipe.

```
tee: /proc/self/fd/13: I/O error
```

Note that while the sorted output is *likely* to come after the non-sorted one, there's no guarantee. More generally, you can't really guarantee the order of output of programs that run concurrently unless there's something that coordinates them.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the behavior as well as providing a solution; so in general it's safe to `tee` to multiple processes as long as each one reads to the end of the stream?